# django-paypal で PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN に設定する値がわからない

Tags: python, django, paypal

django-paypalを使用したいと思っています。

https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/

PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN = "xxx"
に値を設定するのですが、
PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN に相当する番号がどうしても見つかりません。

探した結果
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961544/how-do-i-get-identity-token-in-paypal-sandbox
のサイトがヒットし、

[image: 更新ボタンを押すまで]

[image: 保存ボタンを押すまで]

この操作をしましたが、
その番号は表示されませんでした。
メールで送られれてくるものかと思いましたがそうではありませんでした。
どこにあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[その回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8961552/2818869)から引用して、一部太字にしました。

> Visit the Profile via www.sandbox.paypal.com > Login > Profile and find "Website Payment Preferences", enable 'Auto Return' **and 'PDT / Payment Data Transfer'**.
>   **Once PDT is enabled, you'll be given an 'identity token' for use with PayPal PDT.**

`PDT / Payment Data Transfer` は、質問に貼られたスクリーンショットで言うならば `支払データ転送` が該当するかと思います。それをオンに設定してみてください。

英語ではありますが、一度 django-paypal のドキュメントや、 PayPal のドキュメントを参照されることをお勧めします。

- [Using PayPal Standard PDT — django-paypal 0.2 documentation](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/pdt.html)
- [Classic APIs - Payment Data Transfer product page - PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/)

なお蛇足かもしれませんが、もし支払データ転送を使わないのであれば `PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN` の設定は不要だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。

PDT / Payment Data Transferをオンにしたときに出てきました。
ドキュメントは読みましたが、英語なので重要なところに気が付きませんでした。

しかし、結局PDTではなくIPNを使用しようと思ったので、
PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKENを設定から外しましたが、

    You must set PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN in settings.py. Get this token by enabling PDT in your PayPal account.

のエラーが出てくるのは不可解でした。

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` の記述は修正しましたか？そこに `paypal.standard.pdt` が指定されているときに `PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKEN` をチェックする、と[ソースコードに書かれていました](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/pdt/models.py%23L13-15)。

Comment: paypal.standard.pdtを外してpaypal.standard.ipnのみの設定しています。

一度syncdbしたため関係ないテーブルがあると起こるかもしれないので、
paypal_ipn、auth_permission、paypal_nvpのあとに
syncdbをしなおしましたが出来ませんでした。

Comment: ソースに書かれたコメントではTODOとも書かれていたので、IPNのときでもチェックしてしまうのでしょうか… `urls.py` にもPDT関連の記述は残ってないですよね？

Comment: # ### Todo: Move this logic to conf.py:
このTODOコメントですね？
仕方ないので一応PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKENは残しました。

あと、ついでにお聞きしたいのですが、

https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html
の4番目に書かれているnotify_urlですが、
これは3番目のところの
`"notify_url": "https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),`
から呼ばれることを言ってるのでしょうか？

`url(r'^something/paypal/', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls'), name='notify-url'),`
と書かないと行けないように思います。

Comment: `paypal.standard.ipn.urls` の方で `name='paypal-ipn'` と書かれてるのでいいんじゃないでしょうか https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/blob/master/paypal/standard/ipn/urls.py

Comment: ありがとうございます。
裏で設定を持ってたのですね。

`https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),`ではなく、`reverse`メソッドが勝手にURLを生成してくれるので
`reverse('paypal-ipn')`
だけでいい気がしますが違いますでしょうか？

私はこのnotifyをよく理解してないのですが、何を通知するものなのでしょうか？
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

return_urlについても、
購入後の復帰だと思いましたが戻ってきませんでした。
「ウェブ ペイメントの自動復帰」がPayPalの設定画面で行っても出来ませんでした。
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Comment: だいぶ話がそれてきたので、その二点についてはそれぞれ新しく質問を作っていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21726/discussion-between-shinriyo-and-unarist)しましょう。

Comment: かしこまりました。ここに追加しました。

http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7572/django-paypal-%E3%81%AEpaypalpaymentsform%E3%81%AEnotify-url%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6

Comment: もう一つはこちらに追加いたしました。

http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7573/django-paypal-%E3%81%AEpaypalpaymentsform%E3%81%AEreturn-url%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6

Comment: PAYPAL_IDENTITY_TOKENが必要になってしまう原因はわかりました。

(r'^paypal/pdt/', include('paypal.standard.pdt.urls')),
をurls.pyに残していたからでした。

Comment: この質問はクローズできますか？
とりあえず解決しましたので。

Comment: @shinriyo このサイトでは回答を承認することで解決済みを示すので、このままで大丈夫です。（「クローズ」機能もありますが、回答の追加を制限する機能なのでちょっと用途が違います）

Comment: 有りがとうございました。そのまままにしておきます。