# django-paypal のPayPalPaymentsFormのnotify_url設定について

Tags: python, django, paypal

Django 1.6で、django-paypal を使用しています。
PayPalはIPNを使用しています。

https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html
の3番目です。

PayPalPaymentsFormでのdictの設定で、

```
"notify_url": "https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
```

とありますが

reverseメソッドが勝手にURLを生成してくれるので

```
"notify_url": reverse('paypal-ipn')
```

だけでいい気がしますが違いますでしょうか？

そもそも、私はこのnotifyをよく理解してないのですが、何を通知するものなのでしょうか？

```
When someone uses this button to buy something PayPal makes a HTTP POST
```

購入の処理の裏方作業を勝手にやってくれる何かをするということなのでしょうか。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。IPNをPayPalでのサイトで設定が必要でした。