# django-paypal のPayPalPaymentsFormのreturn_url設定について

Tags: python, django, paypal

Django 1.6で、django-paypal を使用しています。
PayPalはIPNを使用しています。

https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html
の3番目のpaypal_dictの中です。

`return_url`については、
購入後の復帰だと思いましたが戻ってきませんでした。

「ウェブ ペイメントの自動復帰」がPayPalの設定画面で行っても出来ませんでした。

Comment: `return_url`については、「Return to メールアドレス」のボタンを押下すれば変なエラーは出たものの呼べているような気がしました。
これは勝手に復帰してくれないのですね。

`You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 自分のURL/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.`

Comment: urls.pyにて、

`(r'^return-location/(?P<plan>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.return_location'),`

のように行いましたが、なぜか最後にスラッシュを付けるとうまく行かなかったので、

`(r'^return-location/(?P<plan>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.return_location'),`

とやれば戻ってきました。
cancelの時の処理（cancel-location）はなぜかきちんと飛びました。